# How to simulate a data point from a beta-regression (betareg)?

Tags: r, statistics

R beginner here!

I have question regarding the beta-regression respectively the "betareg" model in R.

I want to simulate a data point from the beta-regression for one value (temp 300).
I should test my resulting conversion by first simulating 10 data points for temp=300, and add them to my plot and a fitted line from the regression. These simulated 10 data points should spread out
vertically over the regression line...

The function that generates random samples from a beta-distribution, rbeta, is not the function used for fitting the model... There are different parameterisations of the beta-distribution. I need to convert the estimates derived from betareg into the parameters used in rbeta.

I´m a very beginner in r and can´t figure out how to extract and manipulate the right estimates out of the betareg model to feed in the rbeta to generate datapoints...

This is my code, but i´m pretty shure this is not the tight way...

```
library(betareg)
data("GasolineYield")
model <- betareg(yield ~ temp, data = GasolineYield)
new_temp <- seq(min(GasolineYield$temp), max(GasolineYield$temp), length.out = 100)
preds <- predict(model, newdata = data.frame(temp = new_temp), type = "response")
predicted_values <- predict(model, newdata = data.frame(temp = new_temp), type = "response")
plot(GasolineYield$temp, GasolineYield$yield, xlab = "Temperature (Fahrenheit)", ylab = "Yield", main = "Beta-Regression Model")
lines(new_temp, preds, col = "red", lwd = 2)
specific_temp <- 300
new_data <- data.frame(temp = specific_temp)
mu <- predicted_values
phi <- exp(predicted_values)^2
simulated_yield <- rbeta(n = 1, shape1 = mu * phi, shape2 = (1 - mu) * phi)
points(specific_temp, simulated_yield, col = "red", pch = 16)
simulated_yield_300 <- rbeta(n = 10, shape1 = predicted_values * phi, shape2 = (1 - predicted_values) * phi)
points(rep(300, 10), simulated_yield_300, col = "red", pch = 16)
```

Thanks for looking at my problem :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for providing code! The points you're trying to add to the plot are cut off. I would change `plot(GasolineYield$temp, GasolineYield$yield, xlab = "Temperature (Fahrenheit)", ylab = "Yield", main = "Beta-Regression Model")` to `plot(GasolineYield$temp, GasolineYield$yield, xlab = "Temperature (Fahrenheit)", ylab = "Yield", main = "Beta-Regression Model", ylim=c(0,1))`. Ssome points might also be plotted on top of each other. Add some jitter like this `points(rep(300, 10)+rnorm(10,mean=0,sd=2),...`. Change the standard deviation as necessary.

Comment: Thanks! I will transmit this to a few other plots I have and play around with it...

Answer (score 0):

Printing the model shows:

```r
library(betareg)
data("GasolineYield")
model <- betareg(yield ~ temp, data = GasolineYield)
# Call:
# betareg(formula = yield ~ temp, data = GasolineYield)
# 
# Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
# (Intercept)         temp  
#   -3.908231     0.007308  
# 
# Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
# (phi)  
# 26.64
```

The parameter `phi` is `shape1+shape2`, and the parameter `mu`, which is the mean `shape1/(shape1+shape2)` of the Beta distribution, is given by `logit(mu) = intercept + slope*temp`. So you get `shape1` and `shape2` for a specific temp as follows:

```r
specific_temp <- 300
logit_mu <- -3.908231 + 0.007308 * specific_temp
phi <- 26.64                   # this is shape1+shape2
mu <- 1 / (1 + exp(-logit_mu)) # this is shape1/(shape1+shape2)
shape1 <- mu * phi
shape2 <- phi - shape1
```

The predicted response is the mean `mu`, so you can check you get the same value with the `predict` function.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. Trying to wrap my head around it now.